# Logic to Capture the Data through Selnium Web driver - Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am Writing test case wherein i want to capture the data. That is when I click on the download button it shows the percentage progress i.e ( 1%, 2%, 3% and so on till 100%). I want to capture this text that is the Progress shown in the percentage(1%,2% and so on till 100%). I have tried and written the code but it is capturing only the start data i.e 0 and then 0%
Below is the snap and code for your reference
[image]

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='No, thanks!']").click() 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 500)")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'& Sliders')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bootstrap Progress bar").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='cricle-btn']").click()

percentage = driver.find_element_by_class_name("percenttext").text
percentage1 = []
for percent in percentage:
    percentage1.append(percent)
    print(percentage1)

time.sleep(21)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually gets the element located by `percenttext` text one time only while you should get that element and extract it's text in a loop. Like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='No, thanks!']").click() 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 500)")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'& Sliders')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bootstrap Progress bar").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='cricle-btn']").click()

percentage = driver.find_element_by_class_name("percenttext").text
while not '100%' in percentage:
    percentage = driver.find_element_by_class_name("percenttext").text    
    print(percentage)

time.sleep(21)
driver.close()
```